# How do I efficiently evaluate and exclude certain values from a Django queryset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model where I have 4 datetime fields (last_fed is gotten from user input, the others are generated at form creation, not added here for brevity).

```
class EatModel(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    medicine = models.ForeignKey(MedicalInfo, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    interval = models.IntegerField(default=4)
    last_fed = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    second_dose = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)
    third_dose = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)
    fourth_dose = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)
    fifth_dose = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)
    remarks = models.TextField(max_length=140, blank=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I have a generic TemplateView display to output the results to show the various doses.

```
class newlist(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    
    template_name = 'trackerapp/eatmodel_newlist.html'
    login_url = 'eatlogin'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['list'] = EatModel.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return context
```

I want to improve the view so that instead of just displaying all datefields into the template, **I want to evaluate if each of them is lesser than localtime() and if so, I want to exclude specifically those values from the queryset** (so if we're past the datetime for second dose, it just passes to context third_dose and fourth_dose)

I experimented quite a bit with filter, exclude, defer, Q but couldn't get it to still return the row (less unwanted values).

One way that I thought could work was to split it into 3 queries, getting objects that excluded - 1) second_dose<localtime(), 2) third_dose<localtime(), 3) fourth_dose<localtime(), and then calling it via 3 contexts separately in the template.

But 3 queries sound excessive to me. (I implemented this in a detailview, but that was much easier given that I only needed to work with 1 object at any time.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could just do the secondary filtering in `get_context_data`. (I changed this to use `ListView`, since that makes sense for, well, a list view.)

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.views.generic import ListView


class newlist(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = "trackerapp/eatmodel_newlist.html"
    login_url = "eatlogin"
    context_object_name = "list"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return EatModel.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        t = now()
        context["need_second_dose"] = [em.second_dose and em.second_dose < t for em in context["list"]]
        context["need_third_dose"] = [em.third_dose and em.third_dose < t for em in context["list"]]
        context["need_fourth_dose"] = [em.fourth_dose and em.fourth_dose < t for em in context["list"]]
        return context
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but can't get it to work meaningfully. 

I can get context["need_second_dose"], but can't use it to match the actual context["list"] in the template? E.g., using this to check if template should display list.second_dose etc

I currently use a for loop in the template to display the main context['list'].